# Failed to load main.js script from index.html leaves a blank site until refresh

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vite, cicd, rollup

The problem is described on the example of Vite / Rollup bundler + Vue app but it perfectly applies to any other modern web stack.

Vite adds a hash to each js chunk, asset, and as well as to the main.js file. It does this in order to let the client know that the file has been changed and it needs to download the new one. I then have a handler in my Vue app router that in case of an error loading dynamic module it will refresh the page and thus find out the new hashes & new files. The problem is if a hash of the main.js file is being changed the website doesn't get to load the Vue router and doesn't pass through this error handler. It gets stuck in a blank index.html document until a manual refresh of a website. Did anyone consider adding an error handler to the

```
<script type="module" src="/src/main.hash1.js"></script>
```

in the HTML file? My idea is:

```
<script type="module" src="/src/main.hash1.js" onerror="onMainScriptLoadingError"></script>
```

and inside of `onMainScriptLoadingError` putting a
`window.location.reload();`
depending on some value stored in `localStorage`. On one hand to reload the page and download the new index.html with new main.hash2.js to be able to load the new assets. On the other hand to avoid the infinite refresh loop (variable in localStorage with the date of the last forced refresh or something similar).

The only 'solution' I found on the internet is leaving the old main.hash1.js historic files but I don't want to end up with 1000 main.js files on the server. I don't want either to relate the CI/CD build to the previous build. Want to keep it separated & independent.

Any ideas? Does it all make sense? Why isn't it considered in the official documentation of any bundler?

Comment: It's unclear what case you address with "The problem is if a hash of the main.js file is being changed". Under which condition does this happen? New main.hash2.js is deployed together with new index

Comment: Exactly. New main.hash2.js is deployed together with the new index.html but the client who had the app opened in his browser still has the old index.html until refresh. So its trying to make a call for main.hash1.js, doesn't encounter it leaving the page blank. Because no src="/src/main.hash1.js" is loaded

Comment: Why? Are you trying to fix this for a user who loads the page simultaneously with the deployment? The script is loaded at virtually the same time as html. There may be problems with dynamically imported chunks, e.g. in the router, but the possibility of problems with <script> chunk is negligible

Comment: Unless there is something I missed it is not only the case of loading the page simultaneously to the deploy. I open a Chrome tab with my app, I then go to another one. In the meantime I deploy my app and the deploy a new version, changing the main.js hash. After some time I go back to the tab with my app opened and I can only see a blank page with an error log 
assets/main.9152584e.js:1  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Comment: I suppose it might have something to do with Chrome releasing memory of unused tabs(from v 110). I'm still investigating the topic but wanted to open a thread on it in case it is a popular problem that is already solved somewhere. For the moment I only found some group of people leaving the old main chunks on the server, which doesn't convince me as a final solution. I'll investigate other browsers.

Comment: Yes, I'd check tab unloading first. I'm unaware of such behaviour and the necessity to specifically address it. I'd expect index to be reloaded when a tab is reloaded, but this depends on a browser. You can check index.html caching policy, depends on webserver config, try to disable it completely for testing purposes.  Otherwise, yes, deploying several builds at once would be an acceptable workaround. But again, this is not a common problem, this is the reason why there would be no mention in the docs.